Display hosts/services from Nagios XI to Thruk
I installed Thruk 3.16 en Nagios XI 2024R1.1.4 on GCP VM RHEL9.
I want to see Nagios XI items in Thruk backend without Livestatus (excepted if you known how install Livestatus, but it seems to be offcial web site is closed)
My target is to see hosts and services in thruk to manage it easly as I did with Eyes Of Network.
With chatgpt I did thruk backend with a common user between Thruk and Nagios XI and Core.
I can open Nagios XI, Nagios Core end Thruk with the same user without error, but in Thruk I never see Nagios XI items.
My backend :

  
    backendtype     nagios
    name            Nagios Core
    url             https://...websiteurl.../nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi
    username        thruk_user
    password        ...mypwd...
    verify_ssl      0
  

Please can you help me?
Thank you so much

this is not possible, chatgpt lied. livestatus is the way Thruk connects to the nagios core. Do not ask chatgpt for solutions...

Thank you for answer.
You check it's not possible to install livestatus ond RHEL 9 and Nagios XI 2024xxxx?
If it's possible do you know how we can proceed?
